# Delete Method in sqlite only deleting 1 row in listview

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-listview, android-sqlite

I am making a simple app using sqlite. I asked so many question related to this but hadn't got much replies.

I am having a **Problem** with my **delete function** which i want to use in another activity. But its **not working**, As i am **using Custom Listview** so I have 2 buttons on row of dynamically created list, one for Update the content and second for deleting the row of the list.

Actually the problem which I am getting is when i delete a row by using button on each row. it only delete the first Item of the List View. totally messed up. *Please help me out with this*

*See*:

[image: My View]

**Database Handler** class:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "tt";

    // Table names
    private static final String TABLE_INCOME = "income";
    //private static final String TABLE_INCOME = "income";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_PRICE = "price";
    private static final String KEY_TYPE = "type";
    private static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
    private static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    private static final String KEY_PAY_MODE = "pay_mode";

    Context c;

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_INCOME_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + TABLE_INCOME + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + KEY_PRICE + " REAL,"  
                + KEY_TYPE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_DATE + " TEXT," 
                + KEY_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT," 
                + KEY_PAY_MODE + " TEXT"
                +")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_INCOME_TABLE);
        Log.d(TABLE_INCOME, "table created with "+ KEY_PRICE +" "+ KEY_TYPE +" "
                + KEY_DATE +" " + KEY_DESCRIPTION +" " + KEY_PAY_MODE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_INCOME);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */

    // Adding new income
    void addContact(Income income) {
        try{
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_PRICE, income.getPrice());
        values.put(KEY_TYPE, income.getType());
        values.put(KEY_DATE, income.getDate());
        values.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, income.getDescription());
        values.put(KEY_PAY_MODE, income.getPaymode());

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_INCOME, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Getting single income
    Income getContact(int id) {
        Income income = null;
        try{
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_INCOME, new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_PRICE,
                KEY_TYPE, KEY_DATE , KEY_DESCRIPTION, KEY_PAY_MODE}, null, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            income = new Income(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(1)),
                cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4),cursor.getString(5));
            Log.d("Genrated..", "Sending data");
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return income
        return income;
    }

    // Getting All Income
    public List<Income> getAllContacts() {
        List<Income> contactList = new ArrayList<Income>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_INCOME;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Income income = new Income();
                income.setPrice(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(1)));
                income.setType(cursor.getString(2));
                income.setDate(cursor.getString(3));
                income.setDescription(cursor.getString(4));
                income.setPaymode(cursor.getString(5));
                // Adding income to list
                contactList.add(income);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return income list
        return contactList;
    }

    // Updating single income
    public int updateContact(Income income) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_PRICE, income.getPrice());
        values.put(KEY_TYPE, income.getType());
        values.put(KEY_DATE, income.getDate());
        values.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, income.getDescription());
        values.put(KEY_PAY_MODE, income.getPaymode());
        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_INCOME, values, null, null);
    }

    //Deleting single income
    public void deleteContact(Income income) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_INCOME, KEY_ID + " = ?",new String[] { String.valueOf(income.getID()) });
        db.close();
    }


    // Getting income Count
    public int getContactsCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_INCOME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

}
```

***Implementing in another activity :***

```
String b = Long.toString(_incomelist.get(position).getPrice());
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/Rupee_Foradian.ttf");
            viewHolder.txt_price.setTypeface(tf);
                        viewHolder.txt_id.setText(Integer.toString(_incomelist.get(position).getID()).trim());
            viewHolder.txt_price.setText("` "+b.trim());
            viewHolder.txt_type.setText(_incomelist.get(position).getType().trim());
            viewHolder.txt_date.setText(_incomelist.get(position).getDate().trim());
            viewHolder.txt_desc.setText(_incomelist.get(position).getDescription().trim());
            viewHolder.txt_pmode.setText(_incomelist.get(position).getPaymode().trim());

            final int temp = position;
(convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2))
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            ViewContact.this);
                    alertbox.setCancelable(true);
                    alertbox.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete ?");
                    alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                                    try{                        
                                    Income income = db.getContact(temp);
                                    db.deleteContact(income); //here using my delete function
                                    ViewContact.this.onResume();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Deleted..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                    catch(Exception e)
                                    {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }

                            });
                    alertbox.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                                }
                            });
                    alertbox.show();
                }
            });
```

Comment: this is at least the 4th time you ask the same question. you are mistaking id for position. Use `final temp = getItemId(position);`

Comment: Dude its not working i am using `final int temp = (int) getItemId(position)` @njzk2

Comment: define "not working". Also please consider that A/ I am not in the same timezone as you. B/ I happen to do other things than answering on StackOverflow.

Comment: Please calm down sir! and `final int temp = (int) getItemId(position)` is responding the same as of above query its only deleting 1st row data @njzk2 take your time :)

Comment: your getContact method doesn't use the ID at all ...

Comment: your query should contain something like `KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }` at some point (pretty much like in your delete function, I should point out)

Comment: I have taken the sqlite file from this link whenever you have time you can go through [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) and i am also editing my DBHandler so you can see it

Answer (score 0):

In your function `getContact(int id)` id is the id of the contact .But you arr not using this id in your query. Means you are not using any where clause in your query.Therefore it always returns first row of your db.

Comment: Please read out code again I am returning temp from the position of the ID.. :) So problem is something else.